# Generating the sequence $1,\frac{1}{2},3,\frac{1}{4},5,\frac{1}{6},\ldots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I cannot figure out the $n$th term.

Comment: What if $n$ is odd? What if even?

Comment: $n^{(-1)^{n-1}}$

Comment: Right. I notice how if it is odd it's just n and if it's even it's 1/n but how would I express this??

Comment: Pedro that's good enough for an answer!

Comment: There is a strange dynamics to this question. I mean this question is really trivial (thereby, I absolutely don't want to attack the OP in any way) and as difficult to answer as the rule for the sequence $1,-2,3,-4,5,-6,...$, which seems to be on high school level or so. Yet, somehow this question has attracted 4 different answers, 60+ views, incredibly many upvotes to answers, etc. I am absolutely astonished by such dynamics; it must have to do with some kinds of herding effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n$ is odd, we just get $n$. For example the $3$rd term is $3$.

If $n$ is even, we just get $1/n$. For example the $8$th term is $1/8$.

We would express this as $n^{p}$ where $p$ is some power. This power is $1$ if $n$ is odd, and it is $-1$ if $n$ is even. We know that $(-1)^n$ is $1$ if $n$ is even, and $-1$ if $n$ is odd, therefore $(-1)^{n-1}$ is $1$ if $n$ is odd, and it is $-1$ if $n$ is even. So we find out that: $n^{\displaystyle(-1)^{n-1}}$ is the right answer using the same line of reasoning.

Answer (score 12):

$$
a_n=\begin{cases}
n, &n\text{ odd},\\
1/n, &n\text{ even},
\end{cases}
\quad n=1,2,\dots
$$

Comment: A strange downvote. Here, have my upvote.

Comment: This is a perfectly good answer. +1 from me as well.

Comment: And from me as well! (+1) $\overset{\cdot\cdot}\smile$

Comment: 5 upvotes for an almost trivial question and answer? Then, have yet another one ... :)

Comment: This is becoming comical I must admit...

Answer (score 1):

It is noted that,the even terms follow a geometric series with common ratio = 2. But the odd terms are given as an arithmetic progression series terms.

that is, odd terms can be written as 2n-1 while for the even's it is 2^-n,where n is positive integer.

Comment: No, look again...

Comment: oops @JohnD ,the even terms are like 1/2n..

Answer (score 1):

Is the following approach valid:

$$a_n = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{n} (1-(-1)^{n+1}) + n \left(1-(-1)^n\right) \right)?$$

It does the trick, at least in Mathematica.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain why this is not a good answer? I will appreciate any constructive explanation.